# Automate 24 online internet authentication

Tags: windows, ubuntu, internet, router

I have recently switched to new ISP named Beam. It always asks for username and password at every system restart and also in the middle of the browsing sometimes. I already have a latest router Netgear JWNR2000 and I tried to configure using `PPPoE` mentioning username and password, static public ip and netmask.

It didn't work for me and may be for anybody yet. I guess they are using third party 24 online` for authentication and which allows to login with only IE browsers. I am trying to automate this login process so that I can easily browse internet as soon as I start my computer. If anybody has any trick to achieve this with the router, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming it's right ISP, have you tried the instructions mentioned [here?](http://broadbandforum.in/beam-fiber-broadband/69888-pppoe-setup-beam-fiber-broadband/)

They suggest logging out and releasing your DHCP lease first then creating a new network connection for windows with your login credentials.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work for me in windows. I also use the linux(ubuntu) machine and so I'm trying if it's possible to do with the router.

Comment: I came to know about the `cyberoam` which `24 online` uses and I saw some `cyberoam client` available for download for auto login and I'm trying to do this on linux first. In this case this client should be installed and configured on all the machines, I think. Any more your input is always welcome....